Altair use multiple selections in multi-layer chart
I would like to have multiple selections in a multi-layer chart. One selection should highlight the closest line and the other should highlight the point on each line closest to the current x position of the mouse.
I can achieve this separately as shown below.
Highlight line:
select = alt.selection_point(encodings=['x'], on='mouseover', nearest=True)
line_select = alt.selection_point(fields=['symbol'], nearest=True, on='mouseover')

base = alt.Chart(data.stocks.url).encode(color='symbol:N', x='date:T', y='price:Q')

selected_lines = base.mark_point(opacity=0).add_params(line_select)

line = base.mark_line().encode(
    strokeWidth=alt.condition(line_select, alt.value(3), alt.value(1))
    )

(
    line
    + selected_lines 
)


Highlight points:
select = alt.selection_point(encodings=['x'], on='mouseover', nearest=True)

base = alt.Chart(data.stocks.url).encode(color='symbol:N', x='date:T', y='price:Q')


line = base.mark_line().encode(
    )
marks = base.mark_point(fill='black', strokeWidth=0).encode(
    opacity=alt.condition(select, alt.value(1), alt.value(0)),
    ).add_params(select)

(
    line
    + marks
)


However, if I try to combine them the point selection stops working and only the line selection applies.
select = alt.selection_point(encodings=['x'], on='mouseover', nearest=True)
line_select = alt.selection_point(fields=['symbol'], nearest=True, on='mouseover')

base = alt.Chart(data.stocks.url).encode(color='symbol:N', x='date:T', y='price:Q')

selected_lines = base.mark_point(opacity=0).add_params(line_select)

line = base.mark_line().encode(
    strokeWidth=alt.condition(line_select, alt.value(3), alt.value(1))
    )
marks = base.mark_point(fill='black', strokeWidth=0).encode(
    opacity=alt.condition(select, alt.value(1), alt.value(0)),
    ).add_params(select)

(
    line
    + selected_lines 
    + marks
)


I have also recreated this behavior with a small modification to the example suggested by @r-beginners in the comments.
Example as is:
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
columns = ["A", "B", "C"]
source = pd.DataFrame(
    np.cumsum(np.random.randn(100, 3), 0).round(2),
    columns=columns, index=pd.RangeIndex(100, name="x"),
)
source = source.reset_index().melt("x", var_name="category", value_name="y")

# Create a selection that chooses the nearest point & selects based on x-value
nearest = alt.selection_point(nearest=True, on="pointerover",
                              fields=["x"], empty=False)

# The basic line
line = alt.Chart(source).mark_line(interpolate="basis").encode(
    x="x:Q",
    y="y:Q",
    color="category:N"
)

# Draw points on the line, and highlight based on selection
points = line.mark_point().encode(
    opacity=alt.condition(nearest, alt.value(1), alt.value(0))
)

# Draw a rule at the location of the selection
rules = alt.Chart(source).transform_pivot(
    "category",
    value="y",
    groupby=["x"]
).mark_rule(color="gray").encode(
    x="x:Q",
    opacity=alt.condition(nearest, alt.value(0.3), alt.value(0)),
    tooltip=[alt.Tooltip(c, type="quantitative") for c in columns],
).add_params(nearest)


# Put the five layers into a chart and bind the data
alt.layer(
    line, points, rules
).properties(
    width=600, height=300
)


I can create a line selector by adding this line of code
nearest_line = alt.selection_point(nearest=True, on="mouseover", fields=["category"])

and can then highlight the lines by changing the line definition to:
# The basic line
line = alt.Chart(source).mark_line(interpolate="basis").encode(
    x="x:Q",
    y="y:Q",
    color="category:N",
    strokeWidth=alt.condition(nearest_line, alt.value(3), alt.value(1)),
)

I then tried to attach the new parameter to all three layers, and it did not work for any case.

Line layer (all lines show true condition, 3 stroke width)
Points layer (Line highlight works, but points/tooltips no longer appear)
Rules layer (all lines show false condition, 1 stroke width)


Is the graph you are looking for this graph in the reference?

That chart has half of what I’m looking for, but unfortunately when combined with line highlight it no longer works.

@r-beginners I have attempted to modify the example you suggested, and I see the same behavior as in my example. They work separately, but not together. I have updated the question to include this additional example.
